# Should I use ReCAPTCHA v2 or v3?

Tags: javascript, captcha

I've seen lots of SO posts and other articles on the internet about the differences between Google's ReCAPTCHA v2 and v3, but I'm not sure which one I should use. I'm looking to protect my website's sign up page (React frontend + Node.js backend). Which version of ReCAPTCHA should I choose? I feel like I've seen v2 in more places than v3, but then again, v3 is hidden... What are the security benefits of both versions like? Are websites less secure or considered "older" if they use v2?

Edit: The reason I ask, instead of just going with the newer one, is because I see a lot of sites still using v2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**v3** allows you to verify if an interaction is legitimate with no user interaction. It is a pure JavaScript that compiles a score, giving you the ability to take other actions like requiring additional factors of authentication.

**v2** comes in 2 versions

"I'm not a robot" Checkbox - requires the user to click a checkbox indicating the user is not a robot. This will either pass the user immediately (with No CAPTCHA) or challenge them to validate whether or not they are human.

The invisible reCAPTCHA badge - does not require the user to click on a checkbox, instead it is invoked directly when the user clicks on an existing button on your site or can be invoked via a JavaScript API call. The integration requires a JavaScript callback when reCAPTCHA verification is complete. By default only the most suspicious traffic will be prompted to solve a captcha.

Which one is best for you will be depending on the nature of your website.
For a general use site, I'd certainly use v3 as it minimizes the interruption of users with challenges.

Answer (score 9):

While the other answer describes the different types of *reCAPTCHA* that Google has, it does not address what I think may be the real issues. As I was wondering about this myself, I came across [this article](https://www.fastcompany.com/90369697/googles-new-recaptcha-has-a-dark-side). I summarize what I think is relevant:

> According to tech statistics website Built With, more than 650,000 websites are already using reCaptcha v3; overall, there are at least 4.5 million websites use reCaptcha, including 25% of the top 10,000 sites. (as the 27th of June, 2019)

The data is changing quickly, right now some 2,602,509 sites seem to be using **v3**.

Also relevant, **v3** works better if its code is installed in all web pages of a site. This means less user privacy. Although Google states that:

> reCaptcha’s API sends hardware and software information, including device and application data, back to Google for analysis, and that the service is only used to fight spam and abuse.

So:

- Google **reCAPTCHA v3** is easier for the users, but as more sites use **v3**, more will be the information that Google has about them, as tracking a user across sites that use v3 is technically possible.
- Google **reCAPTCHA v2** takes more work for the user, but seems to be less intrusive regarding privacy.
- **v3** seems to be gaining momentum quickly.
- Google seems committed to maintain both **v2** and **v3** in the future.

Regarding safety, I can tell from experience that **v2** does not stop all spam. This is probably due to spammers using CAPTCHA farms (real people solving the bot's problems.) I don't have that much experience with **v3**.

So IMHO, I would go for **v3** (already widely adopted) unless maximum user privacy is a *must*. But if you are using *Google Analytics* to measure a site's traffic, using **v2** for added privacy may be irrelevant.

Any comment regarding safety of **v3** from a trusted source or site experience will be appreciated!

Comment: I wish Google were a little less vague about the privacy differences. You mentioned that v3 can track users across sites - but V2 can and might do this as well. Additionally, V2 already had an invisible option, so what's the difference between that and v3?

Comment: I have read about both v2 and v3, and v3 seems to be more advanced and also use more information. All the *hype* goes about v3 using *a lot* of information, but I haven´t looked into it. So, if you think that both track users across sites, I would go for v3. If Goole has developed a new version, I would think that the new version will add something the previous did not have... v3 after all may watch all the site and not only the relevant page.

Comment: I'm still a bit perplexed on what to do when a reCaptcha v3 score is too low... Especially for a signup. The main thing I'm trying to prevent is email stuffing &/ email signup spam. So sending a "2FA" challange to the mail seems a bit illogical.